# How to add lock symbol to my website using private SSL in https pages in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I just purchased SSL for my website from hostgator, so that I can add lock symbol in my website, when users visit https://www.mysite.com

For example: i.stack.imgur.com/68EMA.png

Now they have installed the certificate, but I am unable to make this thing visible in my site. When I am opening the site with https:// it shows no lock symbol.

Please help me to show lock symbol and security certificate information when https:// pages open in my PHP Script.

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic and not a real question, voting to close.

Comment: This would be better suited to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: why off topic? I just gave example.

Comment: You have to make sure all embedded media and external assets like scripts, css, and images are using https as well. As in `<img src="https://www.mysite.com">`, if you use relative URLs without `http://` that will work too.

Comment: Thanks Weskey. you helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue might be that you are referencing some resources (css, js, images) by an absolute URI that begins with `http://`. Either make the URIs relative or change them to `https`. This is all assuming you have control over all the content generated.

Comment: thanks it worked. But one more thing i need to ask, that lock symbol shows, which shows: You are connected to mysite.com, which is run by (unknown). Why this unknown? How can i change this?

Comment: For this you will need other type of certificate - EV (extended validation) and you will need to prove your identity before it can be issued. Of course it also costs more

Comment: I have private certificate which is free with the business plan by hostgator

Comment: @user you can generate your own certificates from the command line and upload those to your server.  these are called 'self signed' certificates and offer the same level of protection via encryption of traffic to and from your web server.  However, it is self signed so anyone can make one.  To give users that sense of trust, you need a 'Certificate Authority' (CA) to validate your identity. These CAs are trusted by the browsers themselves and form the basis of trust on the internet.